# Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations. Default export

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

I have been trying to convert one of my projects to Typescript, and have ran in to an issue with one of the node modules that I am using, called Cachegoose. Unfortunately the maintainer hasn't replied to issues in over a year, so I'm attempting to modify the types on my own so my application will build.

When trying to build my app, I get the error

> Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations.

Which is coming from this typescript declaration file. I've tried various things such as exporting the namespace and removing the `export = cachegoose;` line, but this doesn't work the way I need it to. When using `import cachegoose from 'cachegoose';` I should be able to use the default export as a function. `cachegoose()` (basically the top function declaration). I should also be able to use the function clearCache based off of this default export as well, like `cachegoose.clearCache()`. I'm pretty new to Typescript and have been reading over the documentation and trying out various changes to how I export the namespace and functions, but have not had any success.

```js
declare module 'cachegoose' {

    function cachegoose(mongoose: Mongoose, cacheOptions: cachegoose.Types.IOptions): void;

    namespace cachegoose {
        namespace Types {
            interface IOptions {
                engine?: string
                port?: number
                host?: string
                password?: string,
                client?: any,
            }
        }

        function clearCache(customKey: any, cb: any): void;
    }

    export = cachegoose;

}
```

Comment: hey have you found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Ben unfortunately not. I had to scrap it as I didn't have time to try and work through it before our deadlines.